# DAX return ColumnName as the row value

Tags: sharepoint, analytics, dax, powerbi

**Problematic data source**

There is a SharePoint list with columns: Person, Customer, Responsibility, Week_1, Week_2, Week_n. Values are workload estimates in percentage ( and estimated hours are then calculated from avg. working hours).

**Reasoning**

The reason for this is that the list is much easier to use as there is no need to create new line entry for every single week per employee.

**My take on the issue**

You might already see my problem. For painless analytics there should be a similar data model as described in **Reasoning** chapter.

However it should be possible to create required data model. A new column would be created and it should get its "Week"-value from a lookup-function that could return "ColumnName". This is possible in Excel, but for the record I haven't succeeded in PowerBI with DAX functions.

What would be your recommendation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using Power Query to read from the [SharePoint list](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-to-a-SharePoint-List-Power-Query-3226f248-f8b3-4777-82ce-b4ed04dedaaf?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) and the [unpivot](http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2013/11/14/un-pivoting-data-in-power-query/) the data. You can install Power Query in Excel 2010 and Excel 2013. It ships with Excel 2016 named as Get & Transform. And Power Query is available in Power BI Desktop. It is probably a better choice for this than DAX.

Comment: Thank you! That unpivot was just the thing I was looking for. Now I have beautiful graphs!